# What does the Targum have against Tattenai?

Tags: megillat-esther, targumin, ezra-nechemya, haman, persia

In [Ezra 5-6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.5.1-6.13?lang=bi) appears the governor of Ever Hanahar (the southern side of the Euphrates [in this case](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99#cite_note-2)), Tattenai. Tattenai, upon seeing that the Jews got back to building the Temple after several years of not being able to, asks what they're doing and who gave them permission to do so? They answer that they received permission in the time of Koresh. He tells them that he's going to check it out, but meanwhile they can continue their work. [After the proper document is discovered in the Median archives](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.6.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and new documents are commissioned by King Daryavesh, he passes these on to the Jews and doesn't appear again. For all intents and purposes, he seems to have only been doing his job as government official. Nothing bad about checking building permits, right? Moreover, Tattenai even [let them continue working](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.5.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) while he sorted though the bureaucracy ([and considering that the main archives were in Babylon but the document was found in Media](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.6.1?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Ezra.6.1.2&lang2=bi), it was quite some bureaucratic mess).

Targum Yonatan, however, seemed to have viewed him negatively, as he wrote on [Ester 5:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.5.10?lang=bi&p2=Aramaic_Targum_to_Esther.5.10-11&lang2=bi&w2=Reference&lang3=en):

> "וְאִזְדְרִיז הָמָן וְעַל לְבֵיתֵיהּ וּשְׁדַר וּקְרָא יַת רְחִימוֹי וְיַת זֶרֶשׁ רַשִׁיעֲתָא אִנְתְּתֵיהּ בְּרַת תַּתְּנַי פַּחַת עֵבֶר נַהֲרָא:
> וְאִשְׁתָּעֵי לְהוֹן הָמָן יַת יְקָר עָתְרֵיהּ וְהֵיךְ אִתְמַנֵי עִם דוּכְסֵי מַלְכָּא וְהֵיךְ רָהֲטִין קֳדָמוֹי סְגִיאוּת בְּנוֹי דִסְכוֹמְהוֹן מָאתָן וּתְמַנְיָא בַּר מִן עֲסַרְתֵּי אוֹחֲרָנִין דְאִנוּן פּוּלְמַרְכִין עַל פַּלְכַיָא וּבַר מִן שַׁמְשַׁי דְהוּא סַפְרָנָא דְמַלְכָּא..."

Translation: "And Haman hurried and went to his home and he sent and called his friends and the evil Zeresh his wife, duaghter of Tattenai the governor of Ever Hanahar. And Haman told them all of the great things that happaned to him and how he was chosen to be among the lords of the king and how before him run many sons who amount to 208 besides for the last ten who are governors of provinces and besides Shamshai who is a scribe of the king..."

According to the Targum, Tattenai was the father of Zeresh, father-in-law of Haman and grandfather (or at least, step-grandfather) of Haman's children, including [Shamshai, who was one of the leaders of Tzarei Yehudah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.4.8?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) who brought about the cessation of the building of the Temple prior to Ezra ch. 5. It seems that the Targum viewed Tattenai negatively, which makes me wonder why. I saw nothing problematic with what he did; it was actually in stark contrast to what his grandson Shamshai did (with regards to the Jews in Judea). It occurred to me that the Targum may be emphasizing the differences between the different generations of the family, but Rabbi Yosef ibn Yachiya wrote on [Ester 5:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joseph_ibn_Yahya_on_Esther.5.10.1?vhe=Perush_Chamesh_Megillot_u-Ketuvim._Joseph_ibn_Yahya._Bologna:_1538&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...והביא אוהביו וזרש אשתו אשר היתה בת תתני פחת עבר הנהר שונא ישראל..."

Translation: "...and he brought his friends and his wife Zeresh who was the daughter of **Tattenai the governor of Ever Hanahar the enemy of Yisrael**..."

So what did the Targum have against Tattenai? What evil thing did Tattenai do?

Comment: מעשה שהיה כך היה? Doesn't answer ibn Yachiya.

Comment: @Mordechai Of course, but our sages don't name-drop סתם for no reason, even with a tradition for certain figures. Why even mention Tattenai here?

Comment: It shows that Zeresh was from a distinguished family, and doesn't have to speak evil of her father per-se. It could even be that we only know that Tattenai was a hater of Israel from the statements of his daughter, and maybe this *does* explain ibn Yachiya.

Comment: From Darius's answer, it sounds like he thought he needed to stress pretty strongly that Tattenai must not interfere.

Comment: [Shir Hashirim Rabbah 5:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.5.7.1?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he) identifies him as one of the ones involved in the שטנה על יושבי יהודה וירושלים of Ezra ch. 4. So maybe the Midrash (and the Targum) takes the view that his lesser interference in ch. 5 is more because of special Divine providence - "But G-d watched over the elders of the Jews and they were not stopped" (5:5) - rather than because he was a nice guy.

Comment: [Rashi](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%94#%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%94_(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7)(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7)) also identifies the officials as hostile to the Jews ("והשיבו זקני היהודים דבר לאותן הצרים שלא יבטלו את הבנין עד אשר ילך הדבר לדריוש המלך "). Mention of the need for Divine intervention in 5:5 seems to support this perspective, as noted by @Meir.

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe the fact that his son-in-law got executed for trying to harm the Jews made Tattenai less willing to openly start up with them the second time around.

Comment: @Meir Assuming (as admittedly Seder Olam does) that the Purim story occurred before Zerubavel's rebuilding of the Temple

Comment: Maybe the moral is that not everyone who causes troubles for the Jews is a rabid antisemite (since ya he's just a government official checking papers) but anyway it's God sending us messages (so Chazal are creatively showing by framing the story differently by adding in extra details that from our perspective don't dismiss it as something random or incidental)

Comment: But I think the question is broader than this since it's rare to find people that the midrash paints as neutral. Incidental characters are almost always painted as awesome or terrible

Comment: @DoubleAA (first comment): on the flip side, the moral can be (as I think I understand user19400's answer) that an ostensibly benign "government official checking papers" might be doing so knowing (or thinking he knows) full well that said papers don't exist (especially if he and his cohorts worked to make sure of that), and then claim that he was "just doing his job."

Comment: @Meir That's not a moral. That's just a random story. What's the _point_ of telling that story? The Midrash is apparently reframing the story to make the character actually evil. Why? Either to show off that they remember random historical details or to teach a lesson.

Answer (score 1):

In this kings past history the jews were treated favorably .When the gentiles started up with the jews they used caution .
So when he shows up asking for the building permits ,and he knew that they don’t have it ,
neither any record of it  in the kings archives....then obviously the request is not to just
“see “ the permits!

the meforshim say (see malbim EZRA[[6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.6.1?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Ezra.6.1&lang2=bi)/6:2)
that haman and family destroyed all record they knew of in existence of that permission by koresh and that is why it was not found in its proper place

the find in media was miraculous
or one copy was misplaced ,hence why it was not destroyed

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add sources for your answer.